# Typescript not parsed in Svelte html section

Tags: typescript, eslint, svelte

I'm working on a Svelte project, configured to use typescript.

For every element in the `datesToShow` array, a div should appear in the DOM. This is done with the code shown bellow.

```
{#each datesToShow as date}
   <div on:click={() => { changeFocusDate(date) }}> ... </div>
{/each}
```

When clicking this div, a function, `changeFocusDate` should be called and the array element corresponding to this div should be passed.

This all works great. I'm however using typescript with `explicit-function-return-type` enabled, so eslint warns me that my function does not define a return type, which is great. The code does run.
When changing it to `(): void => { changeFocusDate(date) }`, i get:

> Unexpected token  ParseError

It does not seem to understand the colon. The code doesn't run either.

What's going on here? Eslint parses my code as typescript when I forget to declare the type, but it doesn't when I do declare the type. I only encounter this problem in the html of my Svelte files. The typescript inside the `<script>` tag performs well (with `lang="ts"` of course). I'd like to use proper TS inline.

How could this be fixed? I don't think I can move the declaration of the function to the `<script>` tag, as I have to pass `date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to use TS type annotations inside Svelte markup. To still make ESLint happy, you can create a function which returns a function and invoke that.

```
<script lang="ts">
    // ...
    
    function createChangeFocusDateFn(date): () => void {
        return (): void => changeFocusDate(date)
    }
</script>

{#each datesToShow as date}
   <div on:click={createChangeFocusDateFn(date)}> ... </div>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to use local variables and passed arguments, you can use `//@ts-ignore`

```html
{#each options as option}
    <div
        on:change={
        //@ts-ignore
        e => change_event(e, option)
        }
    />
{/each}
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for TypeSript in Svelte markup is now coming in Svelte 5. See [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/9482)